# Separable, metrizable, and second countable spaces

Tags: general-topology, separable-spaces, second-countable

A space $X$ is second countable if it has a countable basis. We say that a space $X$ is separable if there is a set $Y\subseteq{X}$ such that $Y$ is countable and dense in $X$. Show that if $X$ is a metrizable space then $X$ is separable if and only if $X$ is second countable. Then show that the set of real numbers with arrow topology is a separable space.

I've seen proofs of this on a metric space, but how do I extend it to a general topology? And how do I show that the arrow topology is separable when I know it's not second countable?

Comment: What is the arrow topology?

Comment: You've seen proofs of **what** on a metric space? What does "this" refer to?

Comment: It's defined on $\mathbb{R}$ as all intervals {[a,b)}.

Comment: I guess you mean it's the topology on $\mathbb R$ with a **base** consisting of all half-open intervals of the form $[a,b)$? That is usually called the Sorgenfrey topology or the half-open interval topology, and I've heard that some textbook writer calls it the "lower limit" or "upper limit" (I can never remember which) topology. So now some bad person has decided to call it the "arrow topology"? Wow.

Comment: How would you show that the **usual** topology on $\mathbb R$ is separable? Have you tried using the same thing for the "arrow" topology?

Comment: So you know how to prove "separable iff second countable" for a metric space, but you don't know how to "extend it to a general topology"? You ***can't*** extend it to a general topology. But you weren't asked to extend it to a general topology, you were asked to do it for a ***metrizable*** topology. **Hint:** Start by choosing a compatible metric for the metrizable topology.

Comment: Have you tried showing that the set of all rational numbers is dense in the "arrow" topology?

Comment: I did; I don't think it is because there are infinitely many real numbers between the rationals, so it would be easy to define some [a,b) so that it does not contain any rationals.

Comment: If some $[a,b)$ does not contain any rationals, doesn't that mean that the rationals are not dense in the usual topology of $\mathbb R?$ If it's easy, please define some $[a,b)$ (with $a\lt b$ of course) which does not contain any rationals.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood you. Are you saying that for any [a,b) where a<b but a and b are arbitrarily close, the interval contains some rational number?

Comment: Yes, of course. That's why the set of rational numbers is dense in the real line (with the usual topology, or the "arrow" topology, doesn't matter): between any two real numbers there is a rational number.

Comment: For instance, if $a=\pi$ and $b=\pi+0.000001,$ take the rational number $q=3.141593$.

Comment: @bof, $[a.b)$ is a right facing arrow. It's also called the lower limit topology in Munkres. The space $[0,1] \times\{0,1\}$ in the lexicographic order is still called the "double arrow" (think about why this is :)) .It's compact ordered separable and hereditarily Lindelöf but not metrisable.